# Convergence of an infinite logarithmic series.$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^a}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^a}\right)$$

Depending on the parameter $a\gt 0$, test the convergence.
What method should I use?

Comment: What's the lower limit of the sum?

Comment: Did you try the standard tests? (ratio test, for example)?

Comment: They are a little useless with ln's.

Comment: Limit Comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{n^a}$.

Comment: Can you add your own thoughts about this problem? As it is, it looks an awful lot like a homework question without any effort on your part

Comment: I know but I don't know how to format and typing names of methods in English would be hard for me

Comment: For $a\gt 1$, I think convergence can be shown easily. I'm having problems for the the $a\in(0,1]$ part.

Comment: Related question: [Convergent series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^k}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81613).

Comment: For $a>0$, we have $$\frac1{2n^a}\le \frac1{n^a+1}\le\log\left(1+\frac1{n^a}\right)\le \frac1{n^a}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can show for convergence for $a\gt 1$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^a}\right)\lt \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^a}=\zeta(a) ~,~a\gt 1$$

As we know, $\zeta(a)$ converges $\forall~a\mid\Re(a)\gt 1$. Hence, the original sum also converges $\forall~a\gt 1$.

Comment: This is due that to the fact that $\ln(1+x)\leq x~\forall~x\geq 0$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

For $x$ close to $0$, $\ln(1+x)\sim x$.

Comment: You should add some details specific to this case.

Answer (score 0):

$\ln\left(1+\frac1{n^a}\right)\sim\frac1{n^a}>0$ hence your series has the same behaviour as the Riemann series $\sum\frac1{n^a},$ i.e. it converges *if and only if* $a>1.$